# How to sort files by modified date through php

Tags: php, ftp

Background :
I have a anonymous login ftp server, ftp_nlist only list files alphabetically, I would like to get the list of files on the basis of last modified date, recent first. I tried ftp_exec($conn, "ls -t") but I am presented with Permission Denied error, not sure why itsn't working. Well I am working with php-cli and the number of files are in thousands, I just want to work with recent files. Getting the raw list, and finding the date part of the array elements might help, but I hope there is easy way out. When I login via terminal command ls -t works just fine. So wondering why ftp_exec is not working.

Seeking an easy suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you only want to sort the files by last modified date, you can use

```
ftp_nlist($conn, '-t .');
```

This will not tell you *what* the date for each file is, though.

If you want to get the modified date as well, you can use `ftp_rawlist` and parse the output. Here's a quick example I scraped together:

```
$list = ftp_rawlist($ftp, '.');

$results = array();
foreach ($list as $line) {
    list($perms, $links, $user, $group, $size, $d1, $d2, $d3, $name) =
        preg_split('/\s+/', $line, 9);
    $stamp = strtotime(implode(' ', array($d1, $d2, $d3)));
    $results[] = array('name' => $name, 'timestamp' => $stamp);
}

usort($results, function($a, $b) { return $a['timestamp'] - $b['timestamp']; });
```

At this point `$results` contains a list sorted in ascending last modified time; reverse the sort function to get the list in most recently modified first format.

**Note:** `ftp_rawlist` does not provide *exact* modification timestamps, so this code might not always work accurately. You should also verify that the output from your FTP server agrees with this algorithm and include some sanity checks to make sure things stay that way in the future.

Comment: Thanks, I think, I would do with ftp_nlist($conn, '-t .');
But is it possible to reverse the order, currently this gives, most recent at last, I want most recent first. Can do by reversing the array but also just asking. And I think I can use ftp_mdtm() in conjunction. I just want to filter most recent files and work on it,

Comment: @Nitesh: You can use `'-rt .'` to reverse the order.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function which I wrote for just such a task. It was designed for work with local file system but it will work with `ftp://` URLs, as long as your system has `allow_url_fopen` enabled (although `DIR_SORT_ATIME` and `DIR_SORT_CTIME` won't work):

```
// Constants to make usage more reader-friendly
define('DIR_SORT_NAME',  1);
define('DIR_SORT_SIZE',  2);
define('DIR_SORT_ATIME', 3);
define('DIR_SORT_MTIME', 4);
define('DIR_SORT_CTIME', 5);

function readdir_sorted_array ($dir, $sortCol = DIR_SORT_NAME, $sortDir = SORT_ASC) {

  // Validate arguments
  $dir = rtrim(str_replace('\\', '/', $dir), '/');
  $sortCol = (int) ($sortCol >= 1 && $sortCol <= 5) ? $sortCol : 1;
  $sortDir = ($sortDir == SORT_DESC) ? SORT_DESC : SORT_ASC;
  $name = $size = $aTime = $mTime = $cTime = $table = array();

  // Open the directory, return FALSE if we can't
  if (!is_dir($dir) || (!$dp = opendir($dir))) return FALSE;

  // Fetch a list of files in the directory and get stats
  for ($i = 0; ($file = readdir($dp)) !== FALSE; $i++) {
    if (!in_array($file, array('.','..'))) {
      $path = "$dir/$file";
      $row = array('name'=>$file,'size'=>filesize($path),'atime'=>fileatime($path),'mtime'=>filemtime($path),'ctime'=>filectime($path));
      $name[$i] = $row['name'];
      $size[$i] = $row['size'];
      $aTime[$i] = $row['atime'];
      $mTime[$i] = $row['mtime'];
      $cTime[$i] = $row['ctime'];
      $table[$i] = $row;
    }
  }

  // Sort the results
  switch ($sortCol) {
    case DIR_SORT_NAME:
      array_multisort($name, $sortDir, $table);
      break;
    case DIR_SORT_SIZE:
      array_multisort($size, $sortDir, $name, SORT_ASC, $table);
      break;
    case DIR_SORT_ATIME:
      array_multisort($aTime, $sortDir, $name, SORT_ASC, $table);
      break;
    case DIR_SORT_MTIME:
      array_multisort($mTime, $sortDir, $name, SORT_ASC, $table);
      break;
    case DIR_SORT_CTIME:
      array_multisort($cTime, $sortDir, $name, SORT_ASC, $table);
      break;
  }

  // Return the result
  return $table;

}
```

Returns a sorted associative array of the files in the given path to `$dir`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like "ftp_nlist" second arg takes the same args as linux "ls" command (OP should not have used the 'ls', just the switches )

```
$dir_list = ftp_nlist($ftp_conn_id, '-rtla .');
print_r($dir_list);
```